# Calculate polygon area percentage of another polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I have two polygon layers, first is Taiwan County, came with SHP file.
Second is pre-processed WGS84 points, I've converted it to WKF format.

I've successfully imported the two layers in QGIS:

https://goo.gl/photos/ypxLMqRgmgF9PoiM9

Yellow means the grid(polygon) is 100% in one county, and the brown is in more than one county.

```
Data Format :
Taiwan SHP layer , Name : Taiwan , Column : Town_id,County_id
Grid Layer , Column : GID , Polygon (in wkf format)
```

I want to calculate the percentage of each county that contains the grid(polygon) and result in the format.

```
GID County_ID  Town_ID Percentage
300 1          1       0.6
300 1          2       0.4
301 1          1       1
302 1          1       1
303 1          1       0.8
303 1          2       0.15
300 1          3       0.05
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method. Starting from you print screen where the right grid cells are selected use 'Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon Centroids'.  This will create a new points layer for all cells that fall within a county.  Next run 'Count points in polygon' (found in the processing toolbox).  A new layer of the county polygons will be created with a new column to the attribute table (NUMPOINTS as default) this will have the total count of points within each polygon (ergo the total number of complete cells in each county).  Now you can create a new column, using the field calculator in the attribute table, to calculate the percentage:

```
% of total cells: (NUMPOINTS / total number of points) * 100

% Area: (NUMPOINTS * cell area) / Total number of grid cells) * 100
```

Hope this was what you were after.

Comment: Thanks for kindly help from Knightshound. I've done with "COUNT" layer successfully appears , and have question about the rest process. 1.In the PRE-Process layer (the following call the sample-50000 layer) , it has the GID column. But In the COUNT result only have the County layer , it doesn't have connection between GID and County layer . What can I do with join it together ? Thank you !!

Comment: There's a tool called 'Join attributes by location' which you can use to join the attributes of the county layer to the grid cell layer. I don't believe you can create a join the other way around as you will loose data in a many : one relationship.